# Changing the Hostname

Tags: big-sur

Starting with Big Sur, I have trouble setting the hostname for my machine. If I go to `Settings > Sharing` and set the computer name to `<myhostname>`, it will set my hostname to something like `DESKTOP-66SJRDC`. I have no idea where that value comes from.

Then I set the hostname manually in Terminal via

```
sudo hostname <myhostname>
```

and it seems to use the correct hostname now. However once I change the `Computer Name` again in `Sharing` it falls back to some random value and I have to set it in terminal again.

I remember just needing to set the `Computer Name` in earlier macOS versions and not messing about with `hostname`. Did something change in Big Sur?

Where does the random value come from?

Comment: For me my old name was still present in Sharing, but a similar one to yours was set in Terminal. Now, I changed it via Terminal and it seems to work. I will observe.

It started with the update to Big Sur

Comment: My hostname is apparently being set via DHCP. Instead of my computer name (set in Sharing) showing in my prompt, for example, or when running the `hostname` command, the name assigned to my computer by the network admin shows. I guess the network/DHCP-assigned name, when one exists, must take precedence over the locally-set hostname.

Comment: @leanne how can I check this for myself? Is there a way for me to know if DHCP is overriding my usual name? via the terminal

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal: I knew what my network hostname was by looking at my router's DHCP settings. This network hostname was showing in my Terminal prompt. For example, the prompt showed something like `myname@networkname $` instead of `myname@computername $`, with *computername* being what I set in Sharing.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal: I fixed it with [this tip from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/188mn4g/comment/kblpw8x/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) --> `computer_name=${"$(scutil --get ComputerName)"//\%/%%}` followed by `PS1='%n@$computer_name...'` placed in my `.zshrc` file.